# Next JS method to parse an object does not work. Same code works in console

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, square

So I am building an app in NextJS v12.3.1 that uses the Square API to manage retail catalog, orders, etc. I am currently trying to parse a catalog object to get all of the options associated with it and figure out which ones are valid combinations. The relevant Square data structure for the catalog object is here:

```json
{
    "type": "ITEM",
    "id": "KSLMPCLQWPD5UW6SHVLPLUAK",
    "itemData": {
        "name": "Test item",
        "categoryId": "WQDB6T6B2YHFHGTSJGYM7VU6",
        "variations": [
            {
                "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
                "id": "ALIN7UCNWORH2VBQRSWMI2B3",
                "itemVariationData": {
                    "itemId": "KSLMPCLQWPD5UW6SHVLPLUAK",
                    "name": "test 1, test 2-1",
                    "ordinal": 0,
                    "itemOptionValues": [
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "PXPDSW43PUV22C5M7KMDLXXX"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
                "id": "XDITT242LEJVWD5QACEULOV3",
                "itemVariationData": {
                    "itemId": "KSLMPCLQWPD5UW6SHVLPLUAK",
                    "name": "test 1, test 2-2",
                    "ordinal": 1,
                    "itemOptionValues": [
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "EQ5G2K3XM254NKA2C6FFKLAY"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
                "id": "RAXA4IQMUXWBTCR3PBSQRF7F",
                "itemVariationData": {
                    "itemId": "KSLMPCLQWPD5UW6SHVLPLUAK",
                    "name": "test 1, test 2-3",
                    "ordinal": 2,
                    "itemOptionValues": [
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
                "id": "R5RH65BCLE22VI53Y7BN2UJV",
                "itemVariationData": {
                    "itemId": "KSLMPCLQWPD5UW6SHVLPLUAK",
                    "name": "test 2, test 2-1",
                    "ordinal": 3,
                    "itemOptionValues": [
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "PXPDSW43PUV22C5M7KMDLXXX"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
                "id": "ZKSKGVVPRPIB4CQHU5SEU7FE",
                "itemVariationData": {
                    "itemId": "KSLMPCLQWPD5UW6SHVLPLUAK",
                    "name": "test 2, test 2-3",
                    "ordinal": 5,
                    "itemOptionValues": [
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                            "itemOptionValueId": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            }
        ],
        "itemOptions": [
            {
                "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN"
            },
            {
                "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Necessary related Square objects below:

```json
{
        "type": "ITEM_OPTION",
        "id": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
        "itemOptionData": {
            "name": "test options",
            "displayName": "test options",
            "showColors": false,
            "values": [
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_OPTION_VAL",
                    "id": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U",
                    "version": "1679359741810",
                    "itemOptionValueData": {
                        "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                        "name": "test 1",
                        "ordinal": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_OPTION_VAL",
                    "id": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF",
                    "version": "1679359741810",
                    "itemOptionValueData": {
                        "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                        "name": "test 2",
                        "ordinal": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_OPTION_VAL",
                    "id": "75TNTH3W76XDITUDH76JCNSG",
                    "version": "1679359741810",
                    "itemOptionValueData": {
                        "itemOptionId": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                        "name": "test 4",
                        "ordinal": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "ITEM_OPTION",
        "id": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-21T00:49:01.868Z",
        "version": "1679359741868",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "presentAtAllLocations": true,
        "itemOptionData": {
            "name": "test options 2",
            "displayName": "test options 2",
            "showColors": false,
            "values": [
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_OPTION_VAL",
                    "id": "PXPDSW43PUV22C5M7KMDLXXX",
                    "version": "1679359741868",
                    "itemOptionValueData": {
                        "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                        "name": "test 2-1",
                        "ordinal": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_OPTION_VAL",
                    "id": "EQ5G2K3XM254NKA2C6FFKLAY",
                    "version": "1679359741868",
                    "itemOptionValueData": {
                        "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                        "name": "test 2-2",
                        "ordinal": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_OPTION_VAL",
                    "id": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4",
                    "version": "1679359741868",
                    "itemOptionValueData": {
                        "itemOptionId": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                        "name": "test 2-3",
                        "ordinal": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The code I am using to parse the data is below:

```js
export interface OptionValue {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface OptionGroup {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  values: OptionValue[];
}

export interface VariationGroup {
  id: string;
  options: OptionGroup[];
}

export const getValidOptions = (
  objectToCheck: CatalogObject,
  itemsToCheck: CatalogObject[]
): VariationGroup[] => {
  const newOptions = new Map<string, VariationGroup>();
  const itemObjects = itemsToCheck.filter(obj => obj.type === 'ITEM_OPTION');

  if (
    itemObjects.length > 0 &&
    objectToCheck.itemData?.itemOptions &&
    objectToCheck.itemData?.itemOptions?.length > 0
  ) {
    objectToCheck.itemData.variations?.forEach(variation => {
      const test = variation.itemVariationData?.itemOptionValues?.filter(
        option => option.itemOptionId && option.itemOptionValueId
      );
      const optionValues: OptionGroup[] = test
        ? test.map(option => {
            const optionItem = itemObjects.find(
              obj => obj.id === option.itemOptionId
            );
            const optionItemValue = optionItem?.itemOptionData?.values?.find(
              obj => obj.id === option.itemOptionValueId
            );
            const namedGroup = {
              id: option.itemOptionId ?? '',
              name:
                optionItem?.itemOptionData?.displayName ??
                optionItem?.itemOptionData?.name ??
                '',
              values: [
                {
                  id: option.itemOptionValueId ?? '',
                  name: optionItemValue?.itemOptionValueData?.name ?? ''
                }
              ]
            };
            return namedGroup;
          })
        : [];

      if (optionValues?.length > 0) {
        updateMap(newOptions, variation.id, optionValues);
      }
    });
  }
  return Array.from(newOptions.values());
};

const updateMap = (
  newOptions: Map<string, VariationGroup>,
  variationId: string,
  options: OptionGroup[]
) => {
  const existingVariantGroup = newOptions.get(variationId);
  if (existingVariantGroup) {
    const newVariantGroup: VariationGroup = {
      ...existingVariantGroup,
      options: []
    };
    existingVariantGroup.options.forEach(optionGroup => {
      const newOptionGroup = options.find(
        optGroup => optGroup.id === optionGroup.id
      );

      if (newOptionGroup) {
        newVariantGroup.options.push({
          ...optionGroup,
          values: [
            ...new Set([...optionGroup.values, ...newOptionGroup.values])
          ]
        });
      } else {
        newVariantGroup.options.push(optionGroup);
      }
    });
    newOptions.set(variationId, newVariantGroup);
  } else {
    newOptions.set(variationId, {
      id: variationId,
      options
    });
  }
};
```

The problem is that for some reason the first item in the returned `VariationGroup[]` always has every possible value for each combination. The rest of the option groups are parsed fine. Example below:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "ALIN7UCNWORH2VBQRSWMI2B3",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                "name": "test options",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U",
                        "name": "test 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U",
                        "name": "test 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U",
                        "name": "test 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF",
                        "name": "test 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF",
                        "name": "test 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                "name": "test options 2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "PXPDSW43PUV22C5M7KMDLXXX",
                        "name": "test 2-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "EQ5G2K3XM254NKA2C6FFKLAY",
                        "name": "test 2-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4",
                        "name": "test 2-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "PXPDSW43PUV22C5M7KMDLXXX",
                        "name": "test 2-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4",
                        "name": "test 2-3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "XDITT242LEJVWD5QACEULOV3",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                "name": "test options",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U",
                        "name": "test 1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                "name": "test options 2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "EQ5G2K3XM254NKA2C6FFKLAY",
                        "name": "test 2-2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "RAXA4IQMUXWBTCR3PBSQRF7F",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                "name": "test options",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "OFXLPMCIIBBWDCS7QS7VZH4U",
                        "name": "test 1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                "name": "test options 2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4",
                        "name": "test 2-3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "R5RH65BCLE22VI53Y7BN2UJV",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                "name": "test options",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF",
                        "name": "test 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                "name": "test options 2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "PXPDSW43PUV22C5M7KMDLXXX",
                        "name": "test 2-1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ZKSKGVVPRPIB4CQHU5SEU7FE",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "3ZOTKJAEEDYLQN5QSS5VYOEN",
                "name": "test options",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "WJECD5TYW4FOWZED2GLRO6EF",
                        "name": "test 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "G53EFJ4VNZRGNJOWK4CVJ5ZP",
                "name": "test options 2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "VRXUHAMLVOOWCU2FOZBGHYA4",
                        "name": "test 2-3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried several different ways of parsing the results by using Maps vs using custom objects but they always turn out the same. I finally tried this exact code and objects in a js console and it works as expected. Now it is only not working when running the actual application using this same data. Any help in understanding is appreciated. Feels like I'm going crazy haha....

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Could you remove all of the unnecessary content that just visualizes the data structure and show us what request is executed, what it produces inside the console and what it produces in Next.js.